# How to full outer join or join up to 6 (six) SQL Server database tables in C#?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join 6 tables, as shown in this code below and show all in one datagridview from a SQL Server database.

But I get this error

> Incorrect syntax at keyword JOIN

Here is what I have tried - can someone help me out on this please:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(shoolmanangmentconn))
{
    string sql = "SELECT s1.FirstName, s1.LastName, " +
                 "s2.EXAMSMATHEMATICS " +
                 "s3.TOTALMATHEMATICS" +
                 "s4.OVERALLTOTALMATHEMATICS" +
                 "s5.POSITIONMATHEMATICS," +
                 "s6.GRADEMATHEMATICS " +
                 "FROM(SELECT FirstName, LastName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FirstName)As rn1 FROM tbl_TestingTheApplicationsNAME)as s1 " +
                 "FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT EXAMSMATHEMATICS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXAMSMATHEMATICS)As rn2 FROM tbl_EXAMSSCORES)as s2 " +
                 "FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT TOTALMATHEMATICS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TOTALMATHEMATICS)As rn3 FROM tbl_TOTALSCORES)as s3 " +
                 "FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT OVERALLTOTALMATHEMATICS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OVERALLTOTALMATHEMATICS)As rn4 FROM tbl_OVERALLSCORES)as s4 " +
                 "FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT POSITIONMATHEMATICS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY POSITIONMATHEMATICS)As rn5 FROM tbl_POSITIONSCORES)as s5" +
                 "FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT GRADEMATHEMATICS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GRADEMATHEMATICS)As rn6 FROM tbl_GRADESCORE)as s6 ON s1 ON s5 ON s4 ON s3 ON s2 As s6 ON s1.rn1 = s6.rn6=s5.rn5=s4.rn4=s3.rn3=s2.rn2";

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

    dgvRESULTPRINTER.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or WPF?

Comment: You'd be far better off getting the query working in SSMS *before* putting it in your code. Also C# provides a [verbatim string operator, `@`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-verbatim-string-literal/) which if you put at the start of your string means you don't need to keep stopping and starting.

Comment: @kcisrael kicso why you concatenate the sql query?  string sql, you can give the full query and concat only if you are passing parameters to the query. If you can add the table structures, can help in writing the query.

Comment: I cannot see how this query (even with corrected, working syntax) produces a meaningful resultset. Joining on row_number alone makes no logical sense. The unlucky person with the lowest first name is associated with the lowest grades?

Comment: @Gudwlk When _passing_ parameters there is no need to concatenate, e.g. `select Bar from Foo where ShoeSize > @ClownFeet;`. Concatenation is needed primarily to substitute or add object names, e.g. `select @ColumnList from @Table;` doesn't work, or to support SQL injection, e.g. `'select ' + LittleBobbyTables + '; -- Nothing can go worng.'`.

Comment: @HABO I am talking about the C# program. The query can be rearranged. Not about passing param to SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues with this SQL statement.

- You need `ON` after each `FULL OUTER JOIN` describing how the data sets either side of `FULL OUTER JOIN` are associated, not with a series of `ON` at the end.

```
FROM
  (SELECT FirstName, LastName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) As rn1
   FROM tbl_TestingTheApplicationsNAME) AS s1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT EXAMSMATHEMATICS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXAMSMATHEMATICS) As rn2
   FROM tbl_EXAMSSCORES)as s2
ON s1.rn1 = s2.rn2
```

- You need additional commas in the `SELECT` statement between each of the columns.

```
SELECT s1.FirstName, s1.LastName, s2.EXAMSMATHEMATICS, s3.TOTALMATHEMATICS, 
  s4.OVERALLTOTALMATHEMATICS, s5.POSITIONMATHEMATICS, s6.GRADEMATHEMATICS
```

I don't know if this query will work, as you haven't supplied the DB structure, but that should fix the syntax error you are getting.